# Android Facebook shareDialog & postId

Tags: android, facebook, fbsdksharedialog

Is it possible to use standard shareDialog from Facebook SDK and get back postId when 1. Facebook App installed, 2. Application doesn't review by Facebook?

All examples that I found suggest to use MODE=FEED. But with latest facebook SDK it doesn't work.

Am I right understand that publish_actions possible to get only after Facebook reviews application. And app doesn't pass review if app uses only shared dialog. And postId did pass in callback if publish_actions not granted. So circle.... How to brake it?

Comment: Why do you need post ID?

Comment: I have a server side logic for checking details about post. For do it I need to have postId.

Comment: What details do you need and for what?

Comment: server side should to check that post really exists.

Comment: Why do you need to know if the post really exists?